# How do I stop a web view from auto playing videos?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am currently messing around with URLs from Twitch. However, every time I load the URL, the web view will auto play the streamers video (using the default player, AVKit Player).

I cannot figure out how to stop the web view from auto playing. 
I tried forcing a desktop version of the url and loading the url the regular easy way.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webViewTwitch: WKWebView!
var webView : WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Desktop Mode
    webView = webViewTwitch
    self.webView!.uiDelegate = self as? WKUIDelegate webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.twitch.tv/<PUT STREAMER'S NAME HERE>")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url as URL))
    self.view.addSubview(webView)

    //Regular Phone Mode
    //let url = NSURL (string: "https://www.twitch.tv/<PUT STREAMER'S NAME HERE>")
    //let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    //webViewTwitch.load(request as URLRequest)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `webViewTwitch.configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .all`  ?

Comment: Yes, but it still will load up the stream and then automatically go into the full screen  player.

Comment: also you can prevent autoplay in fullscreen by `webViewTwitch.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true`, and I've never seen anything about prevent autoplay, maybe you should check in `html` or `Js` side

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Twitch has an API, https://dev.twitch.tv, where you can get fullscreen clips on an html site without autoplay: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-clips. These html document can be displayed in a webview and integrated in your app.

Comment: The API is perfect and for some reason things are working on a physical device, but not in the simulator. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

Set This property in your WebConfig object.

```
webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .all
```

FYI: You can specify this option for a specific type of audio and video. if you want this action will apply on both just set .all

If this is not working then you need to check your JavaScript code somehow its start by javaScript code. You can try one more thing whenever any URL hit. it must execute this function.

Just open your URL in any browser and search **autoplay** property set this autoplay property to false through javaScript code.